# Which bits of Titanium namespace are available inside webviews?

Tags: javascript, webview, namespaces, titanium

This is here because it took me way too long to discover this on my own.

If you have a Titanium webview which loads a local webpage, the webpage has access to the Titanium namespace. The docs add: "...*in particular* to Ti.App.fireEvent and Ti.API logging functions".

But if you actually load a local webpage into a webview with, say, a button that fires Javascript, you will find that a big part of the Titanium namespace is not available, and calling any of that will kill the Javascript thread.

So which bits are available and which are not? Check out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you don't get logging and event firing stuff *in particular*... those two things are *all* you get.

The Titanium object as supplied to webview looks like this:

```
{ 
  _event_listeners: function(),
  createEventListener: function(listener),
  getEventListenerByKey: function(key,arg),
  API: org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollLogging@40588cb8,
  App: [object]
  executeListener: function (id,data)
 }
```

The Titanium.App object in turn consists of:

```
{
  addEventListener : function(eventName,listener),
  removeEventListener : function(eventName,listener),
  fireEvent : function(eventName,data)
}
```

Any other bit of Titanium is not available. Live with it.

Comment: In addition, firing events from a webview will only work if the event listener was created by the same .js file that opened the webview.

Comment: Furthermore globals like 'require()' are not available, in case that wasn't obvious.